# Guide to large scale LOB application on ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm just starting out on the `ASP.NET Web API`. It seems quite easy enough to adapt. I have been tasked at my organization to re-write our main LOB application, which previously was a desktop based application, to a web based application which needs to handle very large scale datas and relations. Do you think ASP.NET Web API is upto the task? Please also provide any other proven patterns that usually, like banks, provides high security.

Comment: Give us some context.  What do you mean by "very large scale datas and relations"?  100 tables with millions of records?  1000 tables with billions of records?

Comment: This question will elicit too many answers, mostly opinion based. Voting to close.

Comment: Around 5000 tables with millions of records. Its an `ERP` application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Scale:** Without knowing a lot about your specific situation, I wouldn't be too concerned.  The ASP.NET Web API is really just going to exist as a client for the database.  So long as your database can handle the load, you can usually scale out IIS to handle things from a client perspective.

**Security:** The framework is fully capable.  Even if the basic security mechanisms do not meet your needs, there is a rich ecosystem of .NET tools to secure your application.  You'll obviously have to design the system to be secure.  Great tooling can't protect you from an inherently insecure design.

Comment: And what about security, If I chose to use REST API?

Comment: web api can support any type of REST architecture you would want to implement with OAuth and OpenID being the most common although there are many other options.  See http://thinktecture.github.io/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/ or http://thinktecture.github.io/Thinktecture.AuthorizationServer/ for a good "add-ons" to WebAPI security in a REST infrastructure.